# How to simulate visits on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, core-location

how do we simulate a realistic path where you go to a particular location, stop for a while then move on. We are trying to trigger the visit monitoring API. preferably using the iPhone simulator

Answer (score 2):

The simulator has options in the debug menu to simulate location changes.

Maybe temporary switching to a custom location, or simulating a bike ride in between locations, is enough to trigger a visit?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a GPX file. Those files basically contains coordinates that simulates one location or a path.

Here is a very good [article](https://blackpixel.com/writing/2013/05/simulating-locations-with-xcode.html) about it.

In the image below you can see the place in which you must add it in your Xcode project.

Edit Scheme -> Options -> "Default Location" combo -> Select a GPX file...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to subclass CLVisit and override all of its properties. This way you could create mock instances of your choice in order to test your functionality that works with visits.